# How to get logs with nftables, ulogd

Tags: nftables

I have [this](http://ix.io/3Mrf) `nftables` ruleset which resulted mainly from setting up [the simple stateful firewall](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nftables#Simple_stateful_firewall) from Arch Wiki. I then have configured `ulogd` [like this](http://ix.io/3Mri). When ulogd starts up, I see [this log output](http://ix.io/3MHr) in `/var/log/ulogd.log`. However, when I ping `localhost` on the machine itself, or when I ping the machine from a different host, it does not generate any log entries. My log files are always size 0 (see [listing](http://ix.io/3Mrk)).

I can't see where the error is. Can you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add explicit log in your rule

```
root@debian:~# nft list chain ip mon_filtre output
table ip mon_filtre {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 8.8.8.8 log drop
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Why exactly does such an explicit log rule in the output chain help? Is there any text in the nft wiki which I have missed?

Comment: [Link to Wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Logging_traffic)

Comment: Well yes, obviously, I have read that, but nothing in there says that packets from my input chain won't get logged unless I have some specific logging rule in my output chain. Can you please elaborate on why exactly my log files were not being populated until some rule was added in the output chain?

Comment: If you don’t specify any other action , your firewall will  accept or drop the packet and will not any other thing because it’s terminating statement . So in order to enable logging you should explicitly add it on your rules.